# cannot open source file "stdafx.h"

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have two include file headers

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "psapi.h"
```

However it gives a cannot open source file "stdafx.h" compile time error.  I am using Visual Studios 2010.  Is "stdafx.h" even necessary?  I think so because the program cannot compile if i take it away.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Visual Studio uses it for "precompiled headers" feature. If you are not experienced with Visual Studio, I would recommend to keep the stdafx.h in the project.

And of course, if you #include it, you ought to have it.

Comment: And if you include it, then you have to include it FIRST in every compilation unit. The preprocessor will IGNORE every leading line before encountering `#include "stdafx.h"`. You can put anything before, no syntax error.

Comment: @Benoit: My Visual Studio (2010) reports something (at least a warning) when stdafx.h is not the first include.

Comment: Note:  if any **one** file includes `stdafx.h`, then they all should.  I had problems where only one file (from 3rd party) used it, so I had to include it in all my header files.  I prefer not to use it.  My projects aren't big enough to notice any time saved by precompiling; with Visual Studion, the hassle is not worth the savings.

Comment: @Benoit: Your comment should be an answer! I was puzzled for quite some time, when I encountered this error for I found no reasonable explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

stdafx.h is used for precompiled headers.  It is not necessary, but disabling the compiler feature can be a little tricky if you have never done it before.  If you have it, then you must compile 'stdafx.cpp' before compiling anything else.